# update a subfolder that was introduced via git subtree. apply patch isn't working

Tags: git, git-subtree

I want to get 5 more changesets from the remote that I subtree'd into a subfolder and "git apply patch" isn't working, possibly because git apply treats the subtreed folder as a submodule? I got the patches via "git-format-patch".

I'm working on Windows, so I don't have access to the Linux "patch" command. I could spin up a VM and try this on Linux, I could also start googling for "git subtree cherry-pick" (if that's a thing) but I'd sooner get apply working. Any clues? Does it just not work?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this on Linux via the "patch" command thus:

```
patch -p1 < foo.patch
```

Not ideal, but it worked.